# "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" -- Alternatives to JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I am using a library, Instafeed, which creates a `feed` object. The `feed` object is pretty complex.

I need to convert this object to a string value for transfer.

Problem is, I'm getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. All of the answer I've come across say to alter the object to get rid of the circular reference. However, the object is pretty complex and I'd rather not have to do that.

Is there any other way to serialize this object that would avoid the circular reference error?

---

EDIT

Actually, I'm looking at the object in the console and I see this:

[image]

I expanded the `context` key 30 times in total and it just kept going. I'm not having memory issues, and the feed does run fine as intended with the loading of the images as the only delay, so it doesn't seem like this library creating an infinite loop of nested elements.

- Is this just a peculiarity of how the object gets displayed and not indicative of the structure of the object itself?
- And how do I serialize something like this?

---

ALSO, I tried a [JSON-to-XML plugin](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/) but on conversion with that I got the following error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: Probably. How would you like to represent a circular reference?

Comment: What are you doing with this feed? Do you absolutely need to serialize all of it? If not you could use pagination instead, which is mentioned on the Instafeed website.

Comment: @BenSmith I'm actually trying to send the feed object itself over websockets, so yes. There are other ways to achieve the larger goal, but passing it directly would be the easiest.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't understand the question. I'd like to represent it anyway I can to get it serialized.

Comment: There is no silver bullet for representing a circular reference. In general you have to think about what makes an object uniquely identifiable and then use that information as value instead of the object itself. However, in your case it seems like that `context` simply references the object itself. If you can assume that that's always the case then simply set it to e.g, null or remove the property.

Answer (score 2):

Examining https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/blob/master/src/instafeed.coffee, it looks as though the `context` property will sometimes, but not always, be a circular reference. The one thing context is guaranteed NOT to be is `null`.

Test for the circular reference while serializing, and if found, serialize it as null. Deserialize on the other side by re-circularizing it.

(This is an answer only to the specific case, not the general - this object has the good grace to be IMMEDIATELY circular. A multi-step circle would be rather more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data format, not a means of saving arbitrary JavaScript objects.  So trying to push a JS object which is more than just data over the network via JSON sounds fraught.  You might consider whether your design could move just the information that you actually need to move.

That said, it does look like at least one person has tried to solve the circular reference problem [in library form](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json).

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking for alternatives, you should check out the [Circular JSON package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/circular-json).

Replace your calls to `JSON` with `CircularJSON`:

```
function MyCircularClass() {
  this.circular = this;
}

var obj = new MyCircularClass();
var objSerialized = CircularJSON(obj);

console.log(obj);
// ouputs '{ "ciruclar": "~" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your silver-bullet: [cycle.js](https://github.com/dscape/cycle/blob/master/cycle.js). If you're using npm it's available [as a package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cycle) too.

You can use it to de-cycle the object so that it can be serialized with:

```
var stringForm = JSON.stringify(cycle.decycle(myObject));
```

Later if you're loading the object back into javascript you can make it cycled again with:

```
cycle.retrocycle(JSON.parse(stringForm));
```